# Change WooCommerce quantity/productname order in review order checkout table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I would like to change the order of items in the checkout order area.
I want to show the product quantity before the product name.

So instead of:

- Air flow meter oxygen × 1

I would like to show:

- 1 x Air flow meter oxygen

I've managed to find the [review-order.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php) and added it to my child theme so it's update compatible.

I changed the order like this:

```php
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( $cart_item['quantity'], '&times;&nbsp;%s' ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>

<?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>

<?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
```

It now shows:

*x 1 

Air flow meter oxygen*

I can't seem to figure out how:

- I can remove the break after the quantity so it is set on one line.
- And how to change the order of the number and the x

I already switched the `$cart_item['quantity']` and the `'&times;&nbsp;%s'`. But I guess that does nothing. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

To change the order of items in the checkout order area, in [/checkout/review-order.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php) @version 5.2.0

Replace:

```php
<td class="product-name">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
</td>
```

With:

```php
<td class="product-name">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '%s&nbsp;&times;', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '&nbsp;'; ?>
    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
</td>
```

---

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. but for some reason it gives the same result as my code. 
It now shows:

x 1
Air flow meter oxygen: see screenshot: https://prnt.sc/26vnw0e

Comment: @EmileJansen Well, as you can see in the attached image it works for me as expected. The issue for you therefore seems more theme-related or a plugin you use has an influence on it. You can always test/try it with a different theme.

Comment: You are correct, I'll try, the code should be solid. thanks!